# Unityで一定時間後にUI（パネル、ボタン）を表示する方法

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity2d

UIを一定時間後に表示する方法を教えてください。
UIのゲームオブジェクト名はEndSceneで、中にパネルとボタンが3つ（クリックするとシーン移動するもの）存在しています。
最初を非表示にしておき、25秒後にEndSceneごと表示させ3つのボタンを選択できるようにしたいのですが、うまくいきません。
どのようにしたらよいかアドバイスお願いします。
現段階は下のようになっています。
このスクリプトをEndSceneにつけ、EndSceneコンポーネントのEndSceneプロパティにゲームオブジェクト上のEndSceneをドラッグ＆ドロップで設定しています。

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class EndScene : MonoBehaviour
{

    void Start()
    {
        //EndSceneを25秒後に呼び出す
        Invoke("Update", 25f);
    }
    public GameObject endScene;

    void Update()
    {
        endScene.SetActive(true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update() はUnityの特殊な関数で毎フレーム自動的に呼ばれるため、このままではすぐに SetActive が呼ばれることになります。別の関数にしましょう。

あと、時間経過後表示するということなので、ゲームオブジェクトの初期状態は非アクティブ状態であるはずです。ですが、非アクティブ状態では Start() や Update() といったUnityの特殊な関数も呼ばれなくなってしまうので機能しません。
回避策として、このゲームオブジェクトの上位に表示管理用としてアクティブなEmptyゲームオブジェクトを作り、こちらにスクリプトを適用するといった方法があります。

Answer (score 0):

このスクリプトを`endScene`という`GameObject`に付けないで、別の常にアクティブな`GameObject`（例えば`endScene`の親`GameObject`）に付けましょう。

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class EndScene : MonoBehaviour
{

    void Start()
    {
        _startTime = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
    }
    public GameObject endScene;
    private float _startTime;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Time.realtimeSinceStartup - _startTime >= 25f)
            endScene.SetActive(true);
    }

}
```